# Send Key Presses in same manner as Keyboard?

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-7, macros, keypress, sendmessage

I am trying to write a small application for a game I play that allows me to send key presses to it. Unfortunately their software blocks incoming key press events from both SendMessage/PostMessage and SendKeys. Normally I would just say that is intentional and leave it be however...

My G15 Keyboard allows you to create key-binded macros for games, and works fine with this. Since the macros are ran from the keyboard software, they are using some other form of sending key presses than what I have already tried.

Is their a lower level way of doing key presses, or basically sending them in the same manner as if the had been pushed? Here is my code attempts thus far...

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // TRY #1

    IntPtr hWnd = FindWindow("NIVAL_MMO_ENGINE", "Allods Online");
    PostMessage(hWnd, WM_KEYDOWN, ((IntPtr)Keys.W), IntPtr.Zero);

    // TRY #2

    IntPtr Handle = FindWindow("NIVAL_MMO_ENGINE", "Allods Online");

    // Verify that Process is a running process.
    if (Handle == IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Calculator is not running.");
        return;
    }

    SetForegroundWindow(Handle);
    SendKeys.SendWait("w");
}
```

Comment: After reading some more, it looks like I am going to have to either write a Keyboard Driver (not really in my range of knowledge) or find one. Is there any keyboard drivers out there that accept code based input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lowest level way to put keys into the input queue is [SendInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).   If that doesn't work, then the game is doing some interesting things with the input stack.

It's entirely possible that the G15 keyboard supports "hardware" macros - i.e., the *keyboard itself* is generating a series of key up/down events.

Answer (score 2):

To send a key using the function PostMessage, need to define the parameters like this:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, int wParam, Int64 lParam);

public const uint WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
public const uint WM_KEYUP = 0x101;

// sends the W key
PostMessage(handle, WM_KEYDOWN, 0x00000057, 0x00110001);
PostMessage(handle, WM_KEYUP, 0x00000057, 0xC0110001);
```

you can find parameters in Spy++,
Enjoy!!